# Specifying a js to register as a non AMD module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jquery-file-upload

I am currently using jquery file upload plugin
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

The JS files of the component has conditional wrapping for specifiying how to register them either as an AMD module or as an normal module. Below is that conditional Wrap

```
       if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
            define([
                'jquery',
                'tmpl',
                'load-image',
                './jquery.fileupload-fp'
            ], factory);
        } else {
            // Browser globals:
            factory(
                window.jQuery,
                window.tmpl,
                window.loadImage
            );
        }
```

When ever I am including require.js in the jsp file which is needed for other components the above file upload component compoent js files are registering as an AMD modules because of which it is not working as expected.

I need to include file upload components js files in such a way that they will not be registered as AMD module even though I include require JS in my jsp page.

I tried to configure the file upload components using require js as per the given documentation but couldn't able to make it work even though I configured every thing as mentioned in the below URL. So need to know if there is way from which I can tell not register specific JS files as non AMD modules

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-use-jQuery-File-Upload-with-RequireJS

Is there a way in which I can include those JS files so that the above if block will not be executed in those JS files.

Thanks,

Vinay

Answer (score 0):

You could move the script tag for the file upload so it is before requirejs is loaded. However since it relies on jquery then that might not be possible if you want jquery to run after requirejs.

The easiest option would be to edit the code snippet you've shown so that the call to factory() is outside the else block and will always run.